# RSelenium radio button not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, r, selenium, rselenium

I am using RSelenium to scrape content from a website. But when I try to select a radio button it doesn't seem to work.

HTML

```
<div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sex" value="M">
    <label for="sex">
      <span></span> Hombre
    </label>                                    
  <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sex1" value="F">
    <label for="sex1">
     <span></span> Mujer
    </label>
</div>
```

My R code is:

```
sex <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'css', '#sex')
sex$clickElement()
```

But I get the next error:

*Error: Summary: ElementNotVisible*

*Detail: An element command could not be completed because the element is not visible on the page.*

*class: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException*

I have tried using css, xpath, name, id, etc but nothing seems to work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you see other elements on the page with `id="sex"`?

Comment: No, it is the only one. The other id is sex1.

Comment: What browser are you using? You probably need to resize your browser?

Comment: Have you tried maximizing the browser window? `mybrowser$maxWindowSize()`

Comment: I am using ChromeDriver. I tried maximizing the browser window, but that didn't work. Actually, the radio buttons can be seem in the browser window, regardless of the size of the window.

Comment: Have you tried to set a `Sys.sleep(2)` before `sex$clickElement()`? It might be your browser hasn't finished loading yet before you click the element.

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the url of the website in your question?

Comment: Sure.  https://www.autocompara.com/ExpressoAutoCompara/index.htm

Comment: `sex <- mybrowser$findElement(using = "css", ".radio > label:nth-child(2)")` This should work for you. I guess what you can click here is not the input tag but the label. And for the female, it would be `sex <- mybrowser$findElement(using = "css", ".radio > label:nth-child(4)")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem here is that you are not choosing the right element to click. You can find the unique selector by going to the website and inspecting the clickable element and then copying the unique selector at the corresponding HTML element. Here it would be `.radio > label:nth-child(2)`, so you can find the element by `sex <- mybrowser$findElement(using = "css", ".radio > label:nth-child(2)")` and `sex$clickElement()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't know that you could select  the label tag.